# FIFO doesn't block on read

Tags: c, windows

Why the following program doesn't block on the second `read` call?

```
int pid = fork();

if(pid) {
    int fifo = open("testfifo", O_RDWR);

    char buf[20];

    while(1) {
        read(fifo, buf, 10);
        puts(buf);
    }

} else {
    int fifo = open("testfifo", O_WRONLY);

    write(fifo, "teststring", 10);

    close(fifo);
}

return 0;
```

The second `read` call continues returning `0` even though the fifo become empty and it should block on the `read` call.

Am I missing something?

The OS is Windows and the pipe has been created with a `mknod testfifo p`.

Comment: Do *not* ignore the return value of read().  Interpret 0 as "end of file", < 0 as an error.  You should get eof here, you closed the pipe.

Comment: @Simone Apologies for my dodgy edit - obviously didn't intend to damage your question like that!

Comment: @Hans But what i want is the program to block on the read waiting other processes to write on the pipe

Comment: Is this native Windows code or is it running under Cygwin or any similar environment?  If native, whose C runtime library are you using - Microsoft Visual Studio?

Comment: @Harry Johnston Is cygwin. However i solved the problem; i have simply to open and close the file each time in the server cycle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found, from another stackoverflow question, that i should open and close the "server" pipe, in this case the pipe of the parent process, each time; so here's the correct code:

```
int pid = fork();

if(pid) {
    char buf[20];

    while(1) {

        int fifo = open("testfifo", O_RDWR);
        read(fifo, buf, 15);
        close(fifo);

        puts(buf), fflush(stdout);
    }
} else {
    int fifo = open("testfifo", O_WRONLY);
    write(fifo, "teststring", 15);
    close(fifo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the file

EDIT: deleted something embarrassing.

Comment: Tried, but the problem still remain; actually I think that the fifo is closed by the system at the end of the process. Moreover if you look at the code, there is a infinite loop, so the close(fifo) you added is never executed.