# How to communicate between LKM and pthread?

Tags: linux-device-driver

We need to develop a Linux Kernel Module that will handle a hardware interrupt and wake a user pthread (or ideally a C++11 thread).  Is that possible?

Where should I start looking for how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Possible.

LKM need to intimate the user space once the interrupt is occurred in your case.

In ISR, a fifo kind of mechanism can be used to notify to user space. Where as a thread(say pthread) is in blocked read on that fifo can start processing once the LKM writes in to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How does a pthread do a blocked read on a fifo?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256237/fifo-doesnt-block-on-read